# Create new existent folder with an identifier like folder_1, folder_2 etc.. with python

Tags: python, matplotlib, create-directory

I'm creating a new component for my code that can create copies of a folder with an identifier.

For example, I have a serial number and I'm creating a new folder for every serial number, inside every folder exist a new one named with the date that has been created the folder (in every folder i save some PDF's with the serial number with another script). This is the code that I'm using

```py
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
date = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")


from pathlib import Path

def SN_folder(SN, SNs_path):


    if not os.path.exists(f"{SNs_path}/{SN}/{date}/Analysis1"):

        os.makedirs(f"{SNs_path}/{SN}/{date}/Analysis1")
        Analysis1_File_path = SNs_path + '/' + SN +'/' + 'Analysis1'

    if not os.path.exists(f"{SNs_path}/{SN}/{date}/Analysis2"):

        os.makedirs(f"{SNs_path}/{SN}/{date}/Analysis2")
        PHI_File_path = SNs_path + '/' + SN +'/'+ date +'/' + 'Analysis2'

    if not os.path.exists(f"{SNs_path}/{SN}/{date}/Analysis3"):

        os.makedirs(f"{SNs_path}/{SN}/{date}/Analysis3")

        PHII_File_path = SNs_path + '/' + SN +'/'+date+'/' + 'Analysis3'


SN_folder('752-0922', 'SNspath')
```

With this code i'm creating a folder for the Serial Number I'm giving, and inside another folder with the actual date, but if i run my code again with the same Serial Number it overwrites the data saved in this folder, i want to create a new folder with the same serial number and an identifier for the second run like : SN_2 or so.

Comment: not only for the second run, but for maybe 10 different runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not fully understand the problem. but in line `if not os.path.exists(f"{engines_path}/{SN}/{date}/Analysis1")` you should change `engines_path` on `SNs_path`
and most probably response is

```py
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
date = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")


from pathlib import Path

def SN_folder(SN, SNs_path):

    SN_base = SN
    i = 1
    while os.path.exists(f"{SNs_path}/{SN}"):
        SN = SN_base + "_" + int(i)
        i += 1 

    if not os.path.exists(f"{SNs_path}/{SN}/{date}/Analysis1"):

        os.makedirs(f"{SNs_path}/{SN}/{date}/Analysis1")
        Analysis1_File_path = SNs_path + '/' + SN +'/' + 'Analysis1'

    if not os.path.exists(f"{SNs_path}/{SN}/{date}/Analysis2"):

        os.makedirs(f"{SNs_path}/{SN}/{date}/Analysis2")
        PHI_File_path = SNs_path + '/' + SN +'/'+ date +'/' + 'Analysis2'

    if not os.path.exists(f"{SNs_path}/{SN}/{date}/Analysis3"):

        os.makedirs(f"{SNs_path}/{SN}/{date}/Analysis3")

        PHII_File_path = SNs_path + '/' + SN +'/'+date+'/' + 'Analysis3'


SN_folder('752-0922', 'SNspath')
```